# is it possible to covert my priorityqueue back to a LinkedList<Integer>?

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

I am given `k` numbers of `LinkedList<Integer>` and I'm trying to put them into a `PriorityQueue p` in order to sort it.

However, I'm having trouble trying to convert it back into a `LinkedList<Integer>` from the Priority Queue that I have declared.

Here is my code:

```
//Code by Dave S.    
public class MultiMergeWay {
        public static LinkedList<Integer> mergeAll(LinkedList<Integer>[] lists){
            PriorityQueue<LinkedList<Integer>> p = new PriorityQueue<>();
            for(LinkedList<Integer> x : lists){
                p.add(x);
            }
            LinkedList<Integer> array_list = new LinkedList<Integer>(p); //
            return array_list;
        }
    
    }
```

Unless you haven't already seen it, my code wouldn't even compile because of an error in the line marked with a `//`.

Can anyone please explain how can I change my priority queue back to a LinkedList?

Comment: Why do you sort using a priority queue in the first place? Why not use `Collections.sort` or `.stream().sorted(comparator).toList()`?

Comment: Are you trying to sort all `Integer` values across all `LinkedList`s?

Comment: @Savior yes I'm trying to sort them

Comment: Hello , You are passing array of LinkedList to the method, so what exactly you want? Just to sort all elements in LinkedList array then whatever @marstran had suggested is clear.

Comment: What do you think `p.add(x);` does in relation to that kind of sorting?

Comment: @Savior From my understanding of priorityqueues, upon adding x (the linked list) to the queue using p.add(x), it will be sorted already since its a prioriyqueue. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @marstran I need the running time to be as low as possible, which is why I used a priority queue. I need the running time to be O(N logk), where N is the sum of the list lengths and k = lists.length

Comment: @Droid But a priority queue will most likely be slower than just sorting the list in the usual way...

Comment: @marstran isn't collections.sort running time O(nlogn)?

Comment: Yes, but that is the complexity of `Collections.sort` as well. What the big O doesn't recognize, is that you need to loop through all the elements twice to convert back and forth from the LinkedList as well. So that is an overhead you don't get with `Collections.sort`.

Comment: You changed your comment while I was writing my previous comment. Doing `priorityQueue.add(x)` for every element is also `O(nlogn)`, as `add` is `O(log n)`

Comment: @marstran Can you say the compexity of Collections.sort when you don't know the list implementation? Isn't lookup of a LinkedList slow, eg. ArrayList .get is O(1) but LinkedList is O(N) so changing to a new data type could improve the code?

Comment: Shouldn't your priority queue just be `PriorityQueue<Integer>` isn't that where you want to sort the `Integer`s

Comment: @matt I tried to do PriorityQueue<Integer> but then I couldn't do the add() method

Comment: @matt sorry just saw ur answer

Comment: @matt I implicitly meant `Collections.sort` with a linked list. Should have specified it.

Comment: @marstran I check, Collections.sort just delgates to List.sort, which for a LinkedList uses the default implementation. The default implementation creates a Object[] and then uses Arrays.sort. So ArrayList, LinkedList would have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change a few things, if I understand the problem. First make the PriorityQueue a collection of Integer not List

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> p = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

Second in your loop.

```
p.addAll(x);
```

Then your erroneous line, should be correct

Answer (score 0):

Try below answer.
To sort your LinkedList you don't need to use PriorityQueue.
It will simply possible with sorted() method of stream API can help you.

[Collection.sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/)

As you are using Array of LinkedList , java 8 stream API providing [**`flatMap`**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-flatmap-java-examples/) function mapper, which will flat multiple list and then simply applying sorting.

This will help you.

```
public class MultiMergeWay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> array_list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{100, 500, 80}));
        LinkedList<Integer> array_list1 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{200, 600, 90}));
        LinkedList<Integer> array_list2 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1200, 700, 80}));
        mergeAll(new LinkedList[]{array_list, array_list1, array_list2});
    }

    public static LinkedList<Integer> mergeAll(LinkedList<Integer>[] array) {
        System.out.println("Before ==>" + array[0] + " " + array[1] + "" + array[2]);
        var result = Stream.of(array).flatMap(Collection::stream).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("After ==>" + result);
        return new LinkedList<>(result);
    }

}
```

### Output

Before ==>[100, 500, 80] [200, 600, 90][1200, 700, 80]

After ==>[80, 80, 90, 100, 200, 500, 600, 700, 1200]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for ur response. If possible, can you also please show how it would be done using priority queue, since I just want to know what method as well. Like what should I edit in my code?